# Buscar por rango de fechas en un txt

Tags: java

Mi código solo busca dos fechas, no por rangos.

Las fechas tienen formato:
`DateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")`

```
public boolean BuscarLogin(File archivo, String fecha1, String fecha2, ) {

    boolean existe = false;
    try {

        if (archivo.exists()) {

            BufferedReader leerArchivo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo));

            String lineaLeida;

            while ((lineaLeida = leerArchivo.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] palabra = lineaLeida.split(",");
                if (palabra[0].equals(fecha1) && palabra[1].equals(fecha2) && )) {

                    
                   existe = true; }

                }
            }

            if (!existe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay viajes");
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return existe;

}
```

---

Mi pregunta es dónde lo parseo, y en txt es String y el método de buscar busca en String.

Comment: Podrías hacer un volcado parcial del archivo para ver cómo está estructurado, y en qué forma garantizamos que leemos las fechas.

Comment: El archivo txt esta estructurado por String y lo divido por comas nada mas,vu1,QA,2000,01/07/2020,11:11,Internacional de Galeão,02/07/2020,20:00,Internacional de El Salvador,455,208130717,208920345,408910651,208930445,109820345  , Asi es el txt

Comment: En tu código lee una línea del archivo y la subdivide en cadenas cada vez que hay una coma. Ahora palabra[0] y palabra[1] no contiene las fechas de la línea leída. Si cada línea contiene el mismo numero de separaciones por coma. En qué posición se encuentran ambas fechas? Porque según lo que me has pasado seria palabra[3] y palabra[6] si es que lo que has mostrado es una línea. Me podrías aclarar si es como digo, ya que creo que esto es crucial.

Comment: Si es como tu dices el la palabra[3] y palabra[6] contienen las fechas el problema es que yo necesito que me busque en un rango de fechas de la palabra[3] a la palabra[6]

Comment: Entonces qué quieres saber si ambas fechas fecha1 y fecha2 cumplen que están en el rango de palabra[3] a palabra[6].

Comment: Lo que yo deseo saber es que de acuerdo a fecha 1 me busque información hasta que llegue a la fecha 2. ejemplo yo busco todo los viajes de 1/01/2020 hasta 4/01/2020 en otras palabras me tendria que salir los viajes del 1 - 2 - 3 hasta 4 - de enero eso es lo que necesito

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que parsear el texto que lees (si tiene un formato valido) a Date.

Despues podes hacer:

```
fileDate.after(fecha1) && fileDate.before(fecha2);
```

Asumiendo que `fecha1` es el limite inferior y `fecha2` el limite superior

Answer (score 0):

si después de tanto comentar lo he entendido creo que todo pasa por crearte una función que compare si una fecha se encuentra dentro de un rango. Esto lo haríamos así:

```
static boolean DentroDelRango(String Fecha, String FechaRango1, String FechaRango2) throws ParseException 
{
    DateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    
    // Parseamos las fechas
    Date MiFecha = formato.parse(Fecha);
    Date RangoIni = formato.parse(FechaRango1);
    Date RangoFin = formato.parse(FechaRango2);

    return MiFecha.compareTo(RangoIni) >= 0 &&
           MiFecha.compareTo(RangoFin) <= 0;
}
```

En el cuerpo de tu método modificaríamos de la siguiente manera:

```
public boolean BuscarLogin(File archivo, String fecha1, String fecha2) 
{
    boolean existe = false;
    // Esta variable actuará de contador de los viajes encontrados
    int numViajes = 0;

    try 
    {
        if (archivo.exists()) 
        {
            BufferedReader leerArchivo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo));

            String lineaLeida;

            while ((lineaLeida = leerArchivo.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                String[] palabra = lineaLeida.split(",");
                // Aquí dijimos que en Index 3 y 6 tenemos las fechas.
                existe = DentroDelRango(palabra[3], fecha1, fecha2) ||
                         DentroDelRango(palabra[6], fecha1, fecha2);
                // Si está dentro del Rango en este caso operamos
                // contabilizando los viajes que encontramos.
                if (existe) numViajes++;
            }
        }

        if (numViajes == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay viajes.");
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Viajes encontrados: " + Integer.toString(numViajes));
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 
        // Arrojó errores
    }

    return (numViajes != 0);
}
```

Según tu código lees todo el archivo y sólo tratas de averiguar si un viaje está dentro del rango. Con la modificación aportada sabremos cuántos viajes cumplen que están dentro del rango. Y al final devuelve si hubo éxito en la búsqueda.